# Can't add sprite to scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I do not understand why it's not letting me add my ball to the scene. The code below is the only code I'm using.

```
-(void) addBall:(CGSize)size {
ball = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:50];
ball.color = [SKColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:76.0f/255.0f blue:76.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.height/2, self.size.width/2);

[self addChild:ball];
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
/* Setup your scene here */

[self addBall:size];
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you declare `SKShapeNode` as a property. Try setting the position to `CGPointMake(30, 30)` just to see if it's an issue with `self.size` being referenced at that point in time.

Comment: What are you passing as the size variable in the `didMoveToView` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
-(void) addBall 
{
    SKShapeNode *ball;
    ball = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:50];
    ball.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:76.0f/255.0f blue:76.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    ball.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:76.0f/255.0f blue:76.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.height/2, self.size.width/2);

    [self addChild:ball];
}

-(void)didMoveToView: (SKView *)view
{
    [self addBall];
}
```

this works, I tested.

Comment: Why when I do this it adds two nodes instead of just the ball? @Valar Morghulis

Comment: Because it is shapeNode. If you want draw inside of shapeNode you should use 2 nodes. I explained for you with image in edit.

Comment: As @Valar Morghulis said, using 2 nodes is the better way to use an SKShapeNode. If you want 1 node, may I suggest creating an image and making it an SKSpriteNode instead?

Comment: Ohh ok I didn't know it had both fill and stroke layers to it! that makes sense duh! haha